# DHTMLX Scheduler Day View, View event count if multiple events in same hour

Tags: dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

Need to show view more option in Day view of DHTMLX Scheduler,. Like in month view https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_max_month_events_config.html
Thanks

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a feature request or otherwise unclear how it's a programming question.

Comment: Thanks for upvoting.
Actually, If I found any feature on their site then possibly I am not posting a ticket here.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this functionality is available only in the month view.